# UNION with IF statements

Tags: sql-server, select, if-statement, union

I'm writing a query that does various checks on database tables and returns a summary of the result(in a single result set)

```
IF ( select COUNT(*) from member_table WHERE password IS NULL ) > 0
   SELECT 'password check' as name, 'ERROR' as result ,'there is user(s) with blank password' as description
ELSE
   SELECT 'password check' as name, 'COMPLETED' as result, 'OK' as description

UNION

IF ( select COUNT(*) from server_context_properties ) = 0
   SELECT 'context properties check' as name, 'ERROR' as result ,'no context property has been entered' as description
ELSE
   SELECT 'context properties check' as name, 'COMPLETED' as result, 'OK' as description
```

the result table should look like this:

```
name                    result  description
password check          COMPLETED   OK
contex properties check ERROR       no context property has been entered
```

I know that the syntax is incorrect, but I can't think of any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Properties.Name, Properties.Result, Properties.Description
From    (
        Select 'password check', 1 As value, 'ERROR' As Result, 'There is a user with a blank password' As Description
        Union All Select 'password check', 0, 'COMPLETED', 'OK'
        Union All Select 'context properties check', 0, 'ERROR', 'No context property has been entered'
        Union All Select 'context properties check', 1, 'COMPLETED', 'OK'
        ) As Properties
    Join    (
            Select 'password check' As name
                , Case
                    When Exists( Select 1 From member_table Where password Is Null ) Then 1
                    Else 0
                    End As Value
            Union All 
            Select 'context properties check'
                , Case
                    When Exists( Select 1 From server_context_properties ) Then 1
                    Else 0
                    End
            ) As Results
        On Results.Name = Properties.Name
            And Results.Value = Properties.Value
```

Comment: I think this is the best one. seems very extensible and clean too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @passwordcheck INT, @contextcheck INT

SELECT @passwordcheck = COUNT(*) 
FROM member_table 
WHERE [password] IS NULL

SELECT @contextcheck = COUNT(*) 
FROM server_context_properties

SELECT  'password check' as name, 
        CASE WHEN @passwordcheck > 0 THEN 'ERROR' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as result,
        CASE WHEN @passwordcheck > 0 THEN 'there is user(s) with blank password' ELSE 'OK' as description
UNION
SELECT  'context properties check' as name, 
        CASE WHEN @contextcheck = 0 THEN 'ERROR' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as result,
        CASE WHEN @contextcheck = 0 THEN 'no context property has been entered' ELSE 'OK' END as description
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe by doing this :

```
SELECT 'password check' as name, 'ERROR' as result ,'there is user(s) with blank password' as description
WHERE EXISTS ( select * from member_table WHERE password IS NULL )
UNION
SELECT 'password check' as name, 'ERROR' as result ,'there is user(s) with blank password' as description
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * from member_table WHERE password IS NULL )

UNION

SELECT 'context properties check' as name, 'ERROR' as result ,'no context property has been entered' as description
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from server_context_properties)
UNION
SELECT 'context properties check' as name, 'COMPLETED' as result, 'OK' as description
WHERE EXISTS (select * from server_context_properties)
```

Comment: This solution looks the cleanest, but I'm just bit worried that it might cause a performance overhead in executing same query twice for each check.